# The constructor BitmapDrawable() is deprecated fix

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a class that extends BitmapDrawable that looks like this:

```
public class MyDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
    protected Drawable drawable;

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if(drawable != null) {
            drawable.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
    // some other methods...
}
```

and Eclipse warns me that constructor BitmapDrawable() is deprecated. Everything is working just fine but I would like to fix my class so I don't get this message.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently your class has the default constructor MyDrawable() that calls BitmapDrawable(), which is deprecated!

Add a constructor with two arguments (Resources and Bitmap) to your class and call the super constructor:

```
 BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), canvasBitmap);
```

this should fix your problem

Comment: Your answer is helpful, although I had to figure out how to do what you suggested. :) Is this the correct way to do this? MyDrawable(Resources r, Bitmap canvasBitmap) { super(r, canvasBitmap); }